# "Parsing filters unsupported" error during extraction of RAR file

Tags: gnome, files, archive, rar, decompression

I have received an `.rar` which I wish to unpack as it contains something rather important to me that I need to really have now. However even though I can view the contents of the `.rar` archive in the Archive Manager, I am unable to extract it due to this error:

[image: Parsing filters is unsupported error screenshot]

The archive should contain two folders within it, each though contain at least 10 audio files as well as a PDF file each (I don't know what the contents exactly should be except for there should be audio files in there, and the content I have described is what I can see from the Archive Manager's view). So the only thing I am left with except the error is one of the folders and one of the audio files, but it says it has 0 bytes in it.

So how exactly do I fix this problem? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20.

**Information Update:**

In reply to a comment requesting the output from the `dpkg -l unrar unrar-free` command:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  unrar          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
dpkg-query: no packages found matching unrar-free
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which unrar package(s) are installed (`dpkg -l unrar unrar-free` or equivalent `apt` command)?

Comment: @steeldriver: I have updated my question with the information you requested.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install unar
```

I recommend you install only one of these (unrar in my case). Then use archive manager:

```
sudo apt-get install file-roller
```

Answer (score 65):

I did install unrar:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

then to extract, go to the path of the `.rar` file and:

```
unrar x [filename.rar]
```

Comment: The command descriptions displayed via `unrar help` aren’t particularly clear as to what the differences are between the `e` and `x` commands. The `x` command apparently extracts all files into a subdirectory of the current directory using the archive filename sans the file extension as the subdirectory name. The `e` command simply extracts all files into the current directory.

Comment: had to use this method since the file-roller was being a B-word