# Alternative decompressors to libarchive which support RAR file format

Tags: software-recommendation, rar, decompression

As a temporary workaround for [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801426/parsing-filters-unsupported-error-during-extraction-of-rar-file), which [I understand](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/373) is limited to `libarchive`, I would like to finder another program capable of decompressing RAR files, preferably this would be a problem in one of the standard repositories. Any suggestions?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.