# Error -" parsing filters is unsupported" while trying to unpack .rar file

Tags: package-management, downloads, rar

I see that this exact same issue has been raised before 
[Parsing filters unsupported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801426/parsing-filters-unsupported-error-during-extraction-of-rar-file)
but I followed what was suggested 
`sudo apt-get install unrar` and `sudo apt-get install file-roller`
but still got the same error code, so no success. Trying to unpack a rar download from archives. I can read it there but cannot unpack it. Someone there asked the OP to run this code: `dpkg -l unrar unrar-free`

if that is helpful, here is the response

`user@zach:~$ dpkg -l unrar unrar-free
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  unrar          1:5.5.8-1    amd64        Unarchiver for .rar files (non-fr
dpkg-query: no packages found matching unrar-free`

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu!](https://askubuntu.com/), the `unrar-free` package available on `Universe` Repository. add it with following `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update` and install it

Comment: So, can you unpack .rar file?

Comment: Yes, as I said, "that did it." Thanks.