# Ubuntu 18.04 Extracting files "parsing filters is unsupported"

Tags: extract

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop.

I tried extracting a file(~700MB) using `right click+extract here`
but got the following error message:

[image]

The file contains mainly pdfs, but also text files, some executables, but it does have alot of files which themselves have files.

I went through some of the pdfs in the file and found that some of them are open able as normal, yet others give the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Found the same question answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801426/parsing-filters-unsupported-error-during-extraction-of-rar-file).

Install unrar:
`sudo apt-get install unrar`

Go to directory of the rar file:
`cd ~/example/path`

Extract file:
`unrar x fileName.rar`